# How to call celery task with class based method?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the class:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.OM = Omni() # Creates an class object, which makes auth on the web site, for scrapping
    @app.task
    def foo(self, data):
        self.OM.parse(data)
```

So how can I call task with foo method?
Because when I try to do like this, I takes error : Missing argument data. I think it is because calling the method get data as self parameter

```
prs = Parser()
prs.foo.delay(data)
```

How I can to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Creating tasks from methods was possible in Celery 3.x, but it was removed in Celery 4.0 because it was too buggy.

I would create a little helper function:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.OM = Omni() # Creates an class object, which makes auth on the web site, for scrapping
    
    def foo(self, data):
        self.OM.parse(data)

@app.task
def foo_task(data)
    prs = Parser()
    parser.foo(data)


foo_task.delay(data)
```

Comment: Got next error -> Object of type Parser is not JSON serializable
Which serializer I have to use in this case?

Comment: Right, I overlooked this. The easiest way would be to instantiate `Parser` in `foo_task`. Please see my updated answer.